# A button that displays different numbers in succession with one click

Tags: android-studio

Is there any possibility for the button to display 2 different numbers in a time interval in android studio?
I mean click -> number1 -> 1 sec delay -> number2;

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
button.setText("number1");
//1sec delay
button.setText("number2");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running a coroutine something like -

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    var n = 0
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        while(n++ < 10) {
            buyBtn.text = "number$n"
            delay(1000)
          }
        }
});
```